# How to rebuild WinForm with just Designer file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I recently picked up a project of mine from a few months ago that I had stored on Github.  However, there are a number of forms that apparently did not get stored in the repo.  I'm not sure how that happened, but I'm trying to recover as much as I can.

For example:
- CreditsBox.cs
- CreditsBox.Designer.cs

In this case, the CreditsBox.Designer.cs file exists, but the CreditsBox class file does not.  Fortunately, the forms that this happened to didn't have too much login in them, so its trivial to rewrite.  However, it would make it 10x easier if I could somehow rebuild the form with just the designer file?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You are not alone. I had this issue at some point (also GitHub). Luckily, I still had the original virtual machine with code on it, so I just had to add it on version control.

Comment: It happens a lot if you use a form as a base for a new form. Copy and paste it in the same project and start modifying the copied one.  But usually it is the designer and the resx file (if any) that are not added correctly to the version control system (in my case SVN)

Answer (score 3):

The designer file is all you need to re-create the UI of your forms.
You could follow these steps

- Create a new Project.
- Add a form and name its file as CreditBox.cs.
- Use your saved designer file to replace the one created by Visual
  Studio.

As far as I know, the last step could be done also with Visual Studio open but, in any case, better close VS and reopen it afterward.

Of course you could do the same for all other form designer files with the missing main cs file.

Answer (score 1):

So I found a somewhat easy way to fix this.

Create a backup of the .Designer.cs file and delete the original from the project.  Then, create a new form in your project with the original form's name (so dependent methods/calls don't fail).  Then go through your original .Designer.cs file and create the objects simply by dragging from the Toolbox onto the form and naming it to match the original file.  Once you have all of them added (don't worry about styling), copy the old Designer.cs content back in so it will fix the styling, spacing, and all that.  Once you build, the designer will update to the original styling/spacing/etc.

Comment: Simple, and nice